# Understanding an example with the co-ordinates of a point chosen uniformly at random from the cube

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

In this example in my textbook I am struggling to to understand the last expression consisting of the 3 terms. The second part of the example is so:[image]

In the second part I don't understand why the distribution function is equal to those probabilities.

Maybe I don't know of some properties of the max function and hence I don't understand these? Any help that would let me understand this is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part $(1)$.** First convince yourself that the events $(X,Y,Z)\in[m_1,m_2]^3$ and $(M_1\ge m_1\wedge M_2\le m_2)$ are equivalent. When $(X,Y,Z)\in[m_1,m_2]^3$, each of $X,Y,Z$ belongs to $[m_1,m_2]$, so $M_1\ge m_1$ and $M_2\le m_2$. When $(M_1\ge m_1\wedge M_2\le m_2)$, then $X,Y,Z\in[m_1,m_2]$ since $M_1\le X,Y,Z\le M_2$.

Next, $P((X,Y,Z)\in[m_1,m_2]^3)=P(X\in[m_1,m_2]\wedge Y\in[m_1,m_2]\wedge Z\in[m_1,m_2])$$=P(X\in[m_1,m_2])^3=(m_2-m_1)^3$ because $X,Y,Z$ are independent.

---

**Part $(2)$.** Note that$$P(M_2\le m_2)=P(M_2\le m_2\wedge M_1<m_1)+P(M_2\le m_2\wedge M_1\ge m_1)$$since $M_1\ge m_1$ and $M_1<m_1$ are disjoint events. This gives$$F_{M_2}(m_2)=F(m_1,m_2)+(m_2-m_1)^3$$where $F_{M_2}(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $M_2$. It can be calculated as follows:$$F_{M_2}(x)=P(\max\{X,Y,Z\}\le x)=P(X\le x\wedge Y\le x\wedge Z\le x)=P(X\le x)^3=x^3$$for all $x\in(0,1)$. Hence the result.

Comment: In $P((X,Y,Z)\in[m_1-m_2]^3)$ Where does $m_1 - m_2$ come from? I understand what $(X,Y,Z)\in[m_1,m_2]^3$ means, but i'm struggling to understand what $(M_1\ge m_1\wedge M_2\le m_2)$ means .  I understand this $P(X\in[m_1-m_2])^3=(m_2-m_1)^3$ . It's because they are uniformly distributed and their probabilities are each equal to ${(m_2-m_1)}/{(1^3-0^3)}$

Comment: @ThePoorJew Sorry, that was typo and I fixed it. Since $X,Y,Z$ are uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$, the probability that $X\in[m_1,m_2]=\int_{m_1}^{m_2}1dx=m_2-m_1$. The event $M_1\ge m_1\wedge(\text{and})M_2\le m_1$ is the event of the minimum of the random variables, $M_1$, being $\ge m_1$ and the maximum, $M_2$, being $\le m_2$, where $m_2\ge m_1$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it!